# Authentication token manipulation error after upgrade from 16.04 -> 18.04 -> 20.04

Tags: 20.04, users, passwd, shadow

### Introduction

I recently upgraded the Ubuntu release from 16.04 to 18.04 to 20.04 and after completing the upgrades and fixing outstanding issues with apps that were running on that local development server I noticed the passwd command to change user passwords has stopped working.

### What is the error

Here is what happens when I attempt to change my own user's password

```
joe@machine1:/etc$ passwd
Changing password for joe.
Current password: 
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
```

Here is what happens when I attempt to change another user's password

```
root@machine1:/etc# passwd openvpn
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
```

### Here is what I tried until now

Here are my attempts after looking at different solutions online.

- I have tried rebooting the system
- I have tried remounting the FS as read,write using this command `mount -o remount,rw /`
- I have tried using `pam-auth-update`
- I have checked the permissions on the following files:

  - `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3790 Aug 17 12:45 /etc/passwd`
  - `-rw-r----- 1 root shadow 2674 Aug 17 13:41 /etc/shadow`
  - `-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 68208 Jul 14 19:08 /usr/bin/passwd`
- I have made sure that there was sufficient space on my filesystem. There is ~300GB free so I don't think that is part of the issue.
- I have used `pwck` which did not really help, here is the output of that command

  ```
  user 'lp': directory '/var/spool/lpd' does not exist
  user 'news': directory '/var/spool/news' does not exist
  user 'uucp': directory '/var/spool/uucp' does not exist
  user 'list': directory '/var/list' does not exist
  user 'irc': directory '/var/run/ircd' does not exist
  user 'gnats': directory '/var/lib/gnats' does not exist
  user 'nobody': directory '/nonexistent' does not exist
  user 'openvpn': directory '/home/openvpn' does not exist
  user 'openvpn': program '/sbin/nologin' does not exist
  pwck: no changes
  ```

Any ideas what could be done to fix this issue. I can confirm that this used to work before the upgrade as I had recently added a user to the system.

Comment: You seem to have covered all the "obvious" causes - I think the `passwd:` entry in /etc/nsswitch.conf may be involved as well?

Comment: Any idea what may be wrong with the passwd entry in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`? Right now it looks like `passwd compat lsass systemd` `group compat lsass systemd` `shadow compat` `gshadow files` and then some other entries which I don't think are related (hosts, network, protocols, services, ethers, rpc, netgroup)

Comment: I have no experience with lsass - I assume that's for Active Directory authentication? Are the users whose passwords you are trying to change local or AD users?

Comment: The users are local, lsass is currently not being used.